# How to say increasing or decreasing as one word? Monotoneness?

Tags: calculus, terminology

In Calculus I, I can ask my class to "find the intervals of concavity".    Is there a simpler way to say to say "find the intervals of increasing and decreasing"?  In other words, "find interval of monotoneness?"  or something in that nature?

Comment: Maybe monotonicity ?

Comment: This sounds right.

Comment: Yep, monotonicity. I don't think that "intervals of monotonicity" is simpler than "intervals of increase or decrease" [*note: not "of increasing and decreasing"*], but it sounds more ... self-assured? haughty? pedantic? :)